# Why did the direct disciples of Mahaprabhu not accept any relation with the Madhva Sect?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism, chaitanya, madhvacharya

**Sri Vasudev Sarvabhouma, Kavi Karnapur, Sri Rupa, Sri Sanatana, Sri Srijiva Goswami, Sri Baladev Vidyabhushana --none of them accepted any link between Madhva sect and the Gaudiya Vaishnava sect**.(Reference: Mahaprabhu Sri Chaitanya, Radhagovinda Nath, Sadhana Prakashani, Page 753.

Why were they of this opinion?

It is interesting because some prefer to call them as the Madhva-Gaudiya sect in these days.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**There is clear evidence in Sri Chaitanya Charitamrita that Mahaprabhu did not consider Himself a follower of the Madhva sect.**

Its true that Sri Chaitanyadeva was a disciple of Sripad  Iswarpuri, Who was from Madhva lineage. Sri Chaitanya was God Himself Who incarnated to the earth 'to take the taste of the Radha-bhava and preach the Mahamantra-sankirtana, which is the yuga-dharma'.

So He Himself remeined in Radha-bhava which was not emphasised on in the Madhva lineage. Sri Chaitanya defines Sri Krishna as 'Rasaraja' and 'Kishora'. From Sri Ray Ramananda, Mahaprabhu got the support of Radha-Bhava. He later therefore mentioned both merits and demerits of the Madhva sect.

> Mahaprabhu asked the Tattva-vadi Acharya of the Madhva sect about the goal and ways (Sadhya-Sadhanaa of their sect. The Acharya said : Surrendering the Varnashrama Dharma to Sri Krishna and going to Vaikuntha getting one of the five forms of Mukti. Mahaprabhu said : The scriptures stress on Sravana and Kirtana. These lead to Krishna-Prema which is the highest purusartha. The real devotees reject the five forms of Mukti as of no value. They reject both karma and mukti...Karmi,and Jnani are both devoid of Bhakti. I see that these two (karma and Jnana) are very much present in your sect. Only one quality of your sect is that you regard Sri Krishna as God (Sri Chaitanya Charitamrita 2/9/238-251).

**If Mahaprabhu accepted that He was of the Madhva sect, He could never mention the Madhva sect as 'Your sect' to the Acharya of the Madhva sect.** **He never mentioned it as 'Our' sect. So it is very clear that He did not consider Himself as a member of the Madhva sect.**

Gaudiya Vaishnavas are followers of Mahaprabhu who worship Him as God.So chanting of the Mahamantra,treating Gopibhava and its culmination Radhabhava as the highest bhava and worshipping Sri Chaitanya as God make them different from the Madhva followers.

As Sri Radhagovinda Nath points out in the  vol 1 of his 'Gaudiya Vaishnava Darshana, (page 165-171)

> (a) According to Maadhvas, Iswara is Sevya and Jiva is His sevaka.But the same holds for the other Vaishnava sects also.
>
> (b) The Upasya of Maadhvas is Vaikuntheswara Narayana. The Upaasya of Gaudiyas is Nandanandana Sri Krishna.
>
> (c)  The Upaasana of Madhvas is ten types of bhajana: satya, hita, priya kathana, sasraanusilana, daya, spriha, sraddha, daana,paritrana, parirakshana. According to Gaudiyas, shravana and kirtana are main elements of Upaasanaa.
>
> (d) As mentioned by Mahaprabhu, the Maadhva's goal is five types of Mukti and going to Vaikuntha. Gaudiyas never want Mukti and want to serve Sri Krishna alone.
>
> (e) According to Madhvacharya, gopis are 'Apsara-strees'(wordly  wives having heavenly bodies).This statement is against the scriptures according to the Gaudiyas, who think Radha and Krishna are One. Further, according to Madhva, Brajagopies< Asta-mahishis< Jasoda< Devaki< Vasudev < Arjun<  Balaraama< Brahmaa. So Brahmaaa is the best devotee. Gaudiyas treat this as against the scriptures. They quote from Vamana-Purana to show that Sri Krishna was eager to take the dust of feet of the gopis.
>
> (f) To establish the superiority of Brahma among the devotees, Madhva did not write the commentary of chapters 12,13 and 14 of the 10th Canto of Bhagavatam. This is highly objectionable to the Gaudiyas.
>
> In Vrihad-Vaishnava-Toshini commentary of Bhadgavata by Sripada Sanatana Goswami, a protest agaist the Maadhva sect is recorded.
>
> Sripada Srijiva Goswami in Laghu-Vaishnava-Toshini has strongly protested against the Maadhva views of the Brahma-mohana-leela.
>
> So there is little similarity of the Maadhva and Gaudiya sects. In fact the opinion of Maadhvas is AGAINST the opinion of the Gaudiya sect.
>
> Kavi Karnapur also mentions in Chaitanya-Chandrodaya(8/1) that Mahaprabhu did not accept the opinion of the Madhvas.
>
> Sripad Srijiva Goswami has mentioned the Madhva sect as 'the Other Sect' in his Sarva-Samvaadini. He always refers to Madhva as Tattvavada-Guru, but NEVER as 'Guru of Our Sect'.

By the  way a  similar happening is there is Kavirji's life.He was a disciple of Sri Ramananda, Who was a worshipper of Sri Rama with Form. But Kavir after illumination rejected the worship of God with form and in temples. His followers are known as Kavir-panthis who no longer worship Rama with form and accept Kavirji as an Incarnation of the Supreme Godhead. So Kavir-panthis inspite of having the Ramananda lineage are not followers of that sect.Theirs is a new sect.

Since about hundred years we are hearing the term 'Madhva-Gaudiya' sect coming into prominance (primarily from some individuals who took sannyasa after the Madhva lineage.If we regard Sri Chaitanyadeva and His followers' teachings to be the essence of the Gaudiya Vaishnavism, this term seems unacceptable. These are probably coming from the ones who never read the original books and are not dependent on any authentic sources.**Radhagovinda Nath also established that none of the direct disciples of Sri Chaitanya did accept wearing of coloured clothes or taking external sannyas as their focus is on Seva.What the current Acharyas say about this has nothing to do with my question**. **So the view of Radhagovinda Nath seem absolutely valid.**

One of Radhagovinda Nath's books on Sri Chaitanya is available online here: https://archive.org/details/GauraTattva/page/n1

[image]

**Addition**

One respected Acharya of the Shri-Vaishnava sect is of the same opinion:

> **I also have a strong objection to gaudiyA's position as followers of madhva sAmpradAya as there is no real disciplic line. (disciplic line just doesnot mean guru's sishya is next guru, but the guru's teachings are unchanged by sishya when he becomes guru.) If there were a disciplic line, then gaudiyAs cannot deviate from sri Ananda teertha's pancha-bhEda and formulate their own achintya bhEda-abhEda. It would have been proper to call themselves chaitanya sampradAya, rather than 'madhva-gaudiya' sampradAya if they want to have a different interpretation of vedanta. If a disciplic line is genuine, then they will not deviate from the original teacher's readings (in this case sri madhva's). Hence, I do not see any genuinity of Gaudiyas as a bonafide vaishnava disciplic line, even in the case of Sri madhva being a bonafide AchArya. Hence their teaching that there are 4 bonafide disciplic lines is of little value. I do not mean to offend the devotion of gaudiya vaishNavAs or madhvas, but exposing the truth behind the genuinity of their disciplic lines**. (Reference: http://www.ibiblio.org/sripedia/ramanuja/archives/apr05/msg00016.html)

**UPDATE**

*According to Radhagovinda Nath, **Sripad Ishvar Puri was not a disciple of Madhva sect at all.** The title of the Madhva sect monks is Tirtha, and never Puri.Radhagovinda has also shown with logic that Baladeva Vidyabhushana was earlier a disciple of the Madhva sect and later joined the Gaudiya sect and the Guru-parampara sloka is written by the commentator of Baladeva (who was a Madhva) and not by Baladeva Vidyabhushana.(Reference: Gaudiya Vaishnava Darshan, Page 171-175).*

**So the Guru-parampara shown is other answers is questionable.**

Comment: @PrasannaR The ordering is perfect as the sloka of Madhva is given in the footnote.According to Radhagovinda, Jishnu means Arjuna here.If you need photos of any other point, pl let me know

Answer (score 6):

I generally don't participate in HSE, but I keep observing.

The reference that you provided in the question and elsewhere in your other answers in relation to Gaudiya Vaishnavism are from secondary sources and many times they are cherry picked into the sources which don't present Gaudiya Vaishnavism properly.

The guru parampara is first researched and the full list is mentioned by Kavi Karnapur in his book that was completed in 1576 AD.

These are the all the books where Madhva-Gaudiya link is clearly said:

Gauraganoddesa-Dipika of Kavi Karnapur..
Text 22, https://archive.org/details/gaura-ganoddesa-dipika_201804/page/n1

Bhakti Ratnakara

Narayana Bhatta Caritamrta

Gaura-gana-svarupa-tattva-Candrika of Vishwanath Chakravarty Thakur

Prameya-ratnavali, Govinda-bhasya and Siddhanta-ratna of Baladeva Vidyabhusana
https://archive.org/details/PrameyaRatnavali.AKShastri/page/n33

Especially in Prameya Ratnavali, Baladeva Vidyabhusana mentions the common points of Madhva & Gaudiya school.

In Text 3, he offers special respect to Madhvacharya:

> anandatirtha nama su-kha
>   maya dhaama -yatir jiyat
>   samsararnava taranim -yam
>   iha j anah kirtayanti budhah
>
> All glories to Srila Madhvacarya Svami, the abode of transcendental happiness. Those who are learned and intelligent glorify him, for he is like a boat which enables the conditioned souls to cross beyond this realm of repeated birth and death.

Then he mentions full list in Text 7:

> tatra guru-paramparā yathā sri krsna brahma devarsi badarayana-samjnakan sri-madhva-sri-padmanabha sriman-nrhari-madhavan aksobhya-jayatirtha-sri- jnanasindhu-dayanidhin sri-vidyanidhi-rajendra jayadharman kramad vayam purusottama-brahmanya vyasatirthams ca samstumah tato laksmipatim sriman-madhavendram ca bhaktitah tac-chisyan srisvaradvaita nityanandan jagad-gurun devam isvara-sisyam sri caitanyam ca bhaj amahe sri-krsna-prema-danena yena nistaritam jagat
>
> With great devotion we glorify the spiritual masters in the Gaudiya Vaisnava disciplic successions. A list of their names follows: 1) Krsna, the Supreme Personality of Godhead, 2) Brahma, 3) Narada, 4) Vyasa, 5) Madhvacarya, 6) Padmanabha, 7) Nrhari, 8) Madhava, 9) Aksobhya, 10) Jayatirtha, ll) Jnanasindhu, 12) Dayanidhi, 13) Vidyanidhi, l4) Rajendra, 15) Jayadharma, 16) Purusottama, 17) Brahmanya, 18) Vyasatirtha, 19) Laksmipati, 20) Madhavendra Puri, and 21) Isvara Puri, Advaita Prabhu and Nityananda Prabhu (who were all disciples of Madhavendra Puri). We worship Isvara Puri's disciple, Lord Caitanya Mahaprabhu, the Supreme Personality of Godhead, who delivered the entire universe by granting the gift of krsna-prema (pure love of Krsna).

Madhavendra Puri is also well-known as a Madhva amongst the Vaisnavas of the Vallabhacarya-sampradaya. By the end of his Sri-Vallabha-digvijaya, Yadunatha (16th century AD), grandson
of Vallabhacarya, described the episode of Vallabhacarya’s taking sannyasa
from Madhavendra Puri, whom he describes as a sannyasi of the Madhvasampradaya.
In his Do Sau Bavan Vaisnava Kl Varta, Gokulanatha (l6th century
AD), another grandson of Vallabhacarya, narrated how Vitthalanatha studied the
scriptures from a Madhva renunciant named Madhavendra Puri.5 It is beyond
doubt that Madhavendra Puri was the guru of Isvara Puri, from whom Lord
Caitanya received diksa.

I have taken many points from here:

https://archive.org/details/BrahmaSutraKarikaBhasyam/page/n5.

You may read from Page 6 to Page 22. I gave some primary references also above.

Though direct followers of Madhvacharya don't have this full record, they acknowledge meeting of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu and Vyasatirtha and Gaudiya sampradaya being part of Madhva Sampradaya. Gaudiya Sampradaya is not an independent one and only misguided or uninformed Gaudiya Vaishnavas think that they are independent sampradaya.

[image]

There are letters written by other mutts of Udupi. Since they are in Kannada, I am not attaching them.

Comment: I do not think the scholars like Radhagovinda Nath would write anything baseless. For Mahaprabhu's followers, the Guru-Parampara is NOT that important as Mahaprabhu was a disciple of Kesava Bharatiji, who was a Vedantist monk. Achintya-vedaveda is completely different from Dvaita philosophy ofSri Madhva.In Chaitanya Charitamrita 2/9/235-51 Mahaprabhu mentions both merits and demerits of the Madhva sampradaya. He also criticised the Madhva Philosophy in front of Sri Vasudeva Saarvavouma and embraced Ray Ramananda's views which basically is Achintya Bhedaabhedavada.

Comment: @Partha this also you must have got from secondary source.. Show me the proof of what you said in primary source. I am aware of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu discussion with Madhvas in Udupi as mentioned in Chaitanya Charitamrta, yes there are differences that's why it is called Gaudiya Sampradaya not Tattvada school. Baldeva Vidyabhusana who discussed common points in Prameya Ratnavali also said the differences in his commentary to Tattva Sandarbha few points of Madhva school that are not accepted by Gaudiya school. Inspite of differences, Gaudiya is still branch of Madhva school.

Comment: @Partha do you think Kavi Karnapurna and Baladeva Vidyabhusana and others have  written baseless things? Though Chaitanya took sanyas in Advaita line, he didn't preach advaita. He preached what Ishwara puri taught him. Factually, his sanyas guru line is irrelevant because except wearing external garments etc.. Chaitanya didn't follow anything of that line.

Comment: @VivekAditya Pl read Chaitanya Charitamrita. I am in no need to show you my sources to you as whatever I want to say has been mentioned in my question and its you who decided to answer.

Comment: @VivekAditya What do you mean by saying that Mahaprabhu did not followi anything of dasanami sannyasa except external garment? This sound strange as He never went beyond scriptural injunctions except in bhava state!!

Comment: @Partha I know what is in Chaitanya Charitamrta. I meant that he externally followed advaita tradition like having no sikha, wearing their type of clothes etc.. Remaining tihing like varnashrama is even followed by Vaishnavas.. That Chaitanya would have followed, even if he didn't take sanyas from advaita line.

Comment: No all Gaudiya Vaishnavas do not obey Varnashrama. They convert non-brahmins to brahmins by initiation which goes against Varnashrama Dharma.

Comment: @Partha my personal opinion is varnashrama is broken and is irrelevant in modern times..

Comment: Thanks, but we are focusing on Mahapraphu and His direct disciples opinion here

Comment: latest addition to my answer also shows how baseless your claim was

Comment: @Partha lol are you kidding? "One respected Sri Vaishnava acharya" ha ha.. Some random Sri Vaishnava writing something and you are using it as a reference. You can read the response also.. you can read response to that as well. www.ibiblio.org/sripedia/ramanuja/archives/apr05/msg00038.html. Even current acharyas refer Madhva sect as Tattvavada sect just like Jiva Goswami did. It is not Baladeva, even before him Vishwanath Chakravarty and Kavi Karnapurna stated the link. Despite differences, they never rejected the link. You shouldn't give much credibility to some local man RadhaGovinda Nath.

Comment: Radhagovinda Nath was a great devotee, a D.Lit., a reputed Principal and scholar. If quoting his analysis is kidding, i am happy to do that:)

Answer (score 3):

It is wrong to say that Gaudiya Vaishnavas do not accept any link with the Madhva Sampradaya. Chaitanya Mahaprabhu was Himself a disciple of a Madhva Guru, Sri Isvara Puri.

**Baladeva Vidyabhusana himself acknowledges the link between the Madhva Sampradaya and the Gaudiya Vaishnava Sampradaya in his "Prameya Ratnavali".**

> *tatra guru-paramparā yathā 
>   sri krsna brahma devarsi
>   badarayana-samjnakan
>   **sri-madhva-sri-padmanabha
>   sriman-nrhari-madhavan
>   aksobhya-jayatirtha-sri-
>   jnanasindhu-dayanidhin
>   sri-vidyanidhi-rajendra
>   jayadharman kramad vayam
>   purusottama-brahmanya
>   vyasatirthams ca samstumah
>   tato laksmipatim sriman-madhavendram ca bhaktitah
>   tac-chisyan srisvaradvaita
>   nityanandan jagad-gurun
>   devam isvara-sisyam sri
>   caitanyam ca bhaj amahe
>   sri-krsna-prema-danena
>   yena nistaritam jagat***
>
> With great devotion we glorify the spiritual masters in the Gaudiya Vaisnava
>   disciplic successions. A list of their names follows: 1) Krsna, the Supreme
>   Personality of Godhead, 2) Brahma, 3) Narada, 4) Vyasa, **5) Madhvacarya, 6) Padmanabha, 7) Nrhari, 8) Madhava, 9) Aksobhya, 10) Jayatirtha, ll) Jnanasindhu, 12) Dayanidhi, 13) Vidyanidhi, l4) Rajendra, 15) Jayadharma, 16) Purusottama, 17) Brahmanya, 18) Vyasatirtha, 19) Laksmipati, 20)
>   Madhavendra Puri, and 21) Isvara Puri, Advaita Prabhu and Nityananda Prabhu
>   (who were all disciples of Madhavendra Puri). We worship Isvara Puri's
>   disciple, Lord Caitanya Mahaprabhu, the Supreme Personality of Godhead, who
>   delivered the entire universe by granting the gift of krsna-prema (pure love of
>   Krsna).** (**Prameya Ratnavali, Text 7**)

Comment: The guruparampara is also wrong as Isvar Puriji was not a disciple of the Madhva sect as explained by Radhagovinda Nath. Pl see my update.

Answer (score 1):

They do accept The link with Madhva Sampradaya and Gaudiya Sampradaya.  First of all Srila Baladev Vidyabhushan was not the direct disciple of Lord Caitanya, he was the disciple of Visjwanath Chakravarti Thakur (An Acharya in the lineage of Lord Caitanya).  Srila Baladev Vidyabhushan accepts Gaudiya Sampradaya as a lineage of Madhva Sampradaya and gives the Parampara list as follows

With great devotion we glorify the spiritual masters in the Gaudiya Vaisnava disciplic successions. A list of their names follows: 1) Krsna, the Supreme Personality of Godhead, 2) Brahma, 3) Narada, 4) Vyasa, 5) Madhvacarya, 6) Padmanabha, 7) Nrhari, 8) Madhava, 9) Aksobhya, 10) Jayatirtha, ll) Jnanasindhu, 12) Dayanidhi, 13) Vidyanidhi, l4) Rajendra, 15) Jayadharma, 16) Purusottama, 17) Brahmanya, 18) Vyasatirtha, 19) Laksmipati, 20) Madhavendra Puri, and 21) Isvara Puri, Advaita Prabhu and Nityananda Prabhu (who were all disciples of Madhavendra Puri). We worship Isvara Puri's disciple, Lord Caitanya Mahaprabhu, the Supreme Personality of Godhead, who delivered the entire universe by granting the gift of krsna-prema (pure love of Krsna). (Prameya Ratnavali, Text 7)

Kavi karnapur was However the direct Shiksha Disciple, even the name Kavi karnapur was given to him by Lord Caitanya Mahaprabhu.  Kavi karnapur also accepts Gaudiya Sampradaya as a lineage of Madhva Sampradaya and gives the following Parampara list

Gaura-ganoddesa-dipika (21):
paravyomesvarasyasic chishyo brahma jagat-patiù /
tasya sishyo narado’bhut vyasas tasyapa sishyatam //
suko vyasasya sishyatvaà prapto jïanavabodhanat /
vyasal labdha-krishna-diksho madhvacaryo mahayasaù //
tasya sishyo’bhavat padmanabhacaryo mahasayaù /
tasya sishyo naraharis tacchishyo madhava-dvijaù //
akshobhyas tasya sishyo’bhut tac-chishyo jayatirthakaù /
tasya sishyo jïana-sindhus tasya sishyo mahanidhiù //
vidyanidhis tasya sishyo rajendras tasya sevakaù /
jayadharma munis tasya sishyo yad-gana-madhyataù //
srimad-vishnu-puri yas tu bhaktiratnavali-kritiù /
jayadharmasya sishyo’bhud brahmanyaù purushottamaù //
vyasatirthas tasya sishyo yas cakre vishnu-saàhitam /
sriman lakshmipatis tasya sishyo bhaktirasasrayaù //
tasya sishyo madhavendro yad-dharmo’yaà pravartitaù /
tasya sishyo’bhavat sriman isvarakhya-puri-yatiù //
kalayamasa sringaraà yaù sringara-phalatmakaù /
advaitaà kalayamasa dasya-sakhye phale ubhe /
isvarakhya-purià gaura urarikritya gaurave /
jagad aplavayamasa prakritaprakritatmakam //

```
        Translation:-
```

Brahma, the master of this universe, was the disciple of the lord of the spiritual
world. His disciple was Narada and Vyasa became the disciple of Narada. Suka
became Vyasa’s disciple through the awakening of spiritual knowledge.
Madhvacharya took initiation in the Krishna mantra from Vyasa. Madhva’s disciple
was Padmanabhacharya, whose disciple was Narahari, who was followed by
Madhava Dvija. Madhava’s disciple was Akshobhya, who was followed by Jayatirtha,
Jïanasindhu, Mahanidhi, Vidyanidhi and Rajendra. Jayadharma Muni was one of
Rajendra’s many disciples and Vishnu Puri, the author of Bhakti-ratnavali and
Purushottama the lover of Brahmin culture became his disciples. Vyasa Tirtha, the
author of Vishnu-saàhita, was Purushottama’s disciple. Lakshmipati Tirtha, a
reservoir of devotion, was Vyasa Tirtha’s disciple.
Madhavendra Puri was the disciple of Lakshmipati, and it is by him that this religion
was founded. His disciple, the sannyasi Isvara Puri, took up the mood of conjugal
devotion, while Advaita Acharya [also the disciple of Madhavendra] took up the
moods of servitude and friendship. Gaura (Caitanya Mahaprabhu) accepted Isvara Puri as his guru, and then
flooded the material and spiritual worlds [with divine love].

There was a Saint of the name Hariram Vyas, he was the disciple of Madhavendra Puri (Gurus guru of Lord Caitanya Mahaprabhu mentioned in all biographies of Lord Caitanya) and he later took up the Radha Vallabh Sampradaya and he gives the following list

sri-krishno bhagavan brahma narado badarayanaù |
sri-madhvaù padmanabhas ca nriharir madhavas ca saù ||
akshobhyo jayatirthas ca jïanasindhur dayanidhiù |
vidyanidhis ca rajendro jayadharma-munis tataù ||
purushottamo brahmanyo vyasatirthas ca tasya hi |
tato lakshmipatis tataù sriman madhavendra-yatisvaraù ||
isvaras tasya madhavo radha-krishna-priyo’bhavat |
tasyahaà karuna-patraà hari-ramabhidho’bhavam ||

Read the names here it is in Sequence.

Coming to Jiva Goswami he does accept connection and addresses them as his Predecessor in his Tatva Sandarbha
And says that he is accepting whatever Madhvacharya Quoted without even seeing the Shlokas in the original Scripture and accepts the wordings the Acharyas in his line.

Even in the Pushtimarg  Vallabhacharya lineage, his grandson accepted that Madhavendra Puri was a Madhva Tatvavadi Vaishnav and gave Sanyas to Vallabhacharya.

Narhari Chakravarti Thakur in the lineage of Srivas Acharya and the son of the disciple of Vishwanath Chakravarti Thakur he in his Bhakti Ratnakar mentions the Story of Diksha of Nithyananda Prabhu in the Madhva Sampradaya by Sripad laxmipati Teerth the disciple of the famous Madhva Sampradaya Acharya Vyas Teerth.

Accept the words of Acharyas.  Infact Even the Madhva Sampradaya Acharyas like Srila Vishwesha Teerth Swami Maharaj and other great Acharyas accept that Gaudiya Sampradaya is a lineage of Madhva Sampradaya and Lord Caitanya took Diksha from the Madhva Sampradaya. The proof is the Udupi Ashtha Matha Letters to Gaudiya by the Madhva Sampradaya Acharyas

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://gosai.com/letters/udupi-asta-matha&ved=2ahUKEwiFw-zLmJfwAhWf7HMBHaViD4UQFjABegQIBxAC&usg=AOvVaw1vaUQb2ud6hgFoud28YyFl

This is the link.  If u are unable to open this link then just search Udupi Ashtha Matha Letters in Google and u will find it.

All glories to Guru and Gauranga, All glories to Srila Prabhupad, All glories to Vaishnavas

Hare Krishna

Comment: Namaste! Welcome to HSE. While you’re browsing the site just for information and future answers you can have a look at the help centre on answering and [Guidelines for new users answering](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions)